# The assignment to a variable name has no effect

Tags: java

I have the below syntax:

#### 1

```
public static String getName() { 
    return (fullName= firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

and it throws an error.  However, if I use

#### 2

```
public static String getName() { 
   fullName=firstName + " " + lastName;
   return fullName; 
}
```

the problem is resolved.

**Question:**
Why is the assignment to `fullName` not working as per #1 and why do I get an error on the field `fullName` as `fullName` is not being used if I use the #1 Syntax ??

Comment: What's the error thrown? Do you mean a pre-compilation error?

Comment: Works for me, although the `fullName = fullName` assignment is pointless.

Comment: Also, how are the static constants initialized?

Answer (score 1):

```
return (fullName = fullName=firstName + " " + lastName);
```

You should to separate this code. First you assign new value for full name (with only 1 assign operator =), then return full name.

Another way is just say:

```
return firstName + " " + lastName;
```

**PS:** Yes you're right, assign expression will run first, then it return the new value of full name.

Answer (score 0):

It is works for me. There is example of usage.

```
public class Test {

    private static String fullName;
    private static String firstName = "FirstName";
    private static String lastName = "LastName";

    public static String getName() {
        return (fullName = fullName=firstName + " " + lastName);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getName());
    }
}
```

But logically there is two mistakes:

1. `fullName = fullName` Assigning field to itself doesn't makes any sense
2. Changing value in method called `getName()` makes a lot of confusion for developers. See [Side effect function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) for more details

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of readability, and for your future and your good habits.
You should write like this:

```
public static String getName() { 
    return firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```